# useState retention scope

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Components A, B and C are functional components. If someState is true and component A is visited, will the useState variables retain their values when arriving back at this module?

The return from A is handled in this main module by passing a callback function to A which resets someState.

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState()
const [anotherState, setAnotherSate] = useState()
...

const handleRemoveDetail = () => {
   someState(0);
 };

return (
  {someState onRemoveDetail={handleRemoveDetail} ? (
    <A />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <B />
      <C />
    </div>
  )}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By conditionally rendering a component, you are **mounting** and **unmounting** it as the condition changes. So to answer your question, no, it will not retain its state values. State is kept during re-renders, but lost when the component unmounts.

However, if the state is managed by a parent component then we are talking about component A's `props`, not `state`. The props of component A will be the same each time it mounts and unmounts as long as the parent component has not changed them.

In addition, this syntax is incorrect, the callback should be provided like this:

```js
return (
  {someState ? (
    <A onRemoveDetail={handleRemoveDetail} />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <B />
      <C />
    </div>
  )}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`A` is not being 'visited', it is being rendered by its parent. The `someState` variable belongs to the parent component, and it will be available as long as the parent is retained. If you pass a `setSomeState` callback to any of the children and call it from there, the state in the parent will update.